# If I save and restore the CurrentGraphicsContext, will that revert my drawing back to original state?

Tags: ios, ios7, cgcontext

I have an iPad app where I draw a grid of dates along the x axis and times down the y axis.  I then draw colored bars (using CGContext methods) in specific sections of this grid (see image).

If I change the data that is used to draw the bars, the old bars are still visible and the new bars are not.  If I use **-CGContextSaveGState** and **-CGContextSaveGState**, will that "clear" the old data so the grid is as it was originally without any bars?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Just the graphical context is restored (graphical engine state machine), not what the engine has produced.

Answer (score 1):

I think Vincent answered your question, but what you need to do now is to redraw all the bars from scratch on the background grid. Call `setNeedsDisplay` for the view that draws the background and the bars when the bar parameters change. Your `drawRect` should then recreate the grid and bars.

Comment: I tried that from -viewWillAppear AND -viewDidAppear, and neither don't even touch redrawing the grid (drawRect)...

Comment: Sorry this reply is so late. Somewhere in your program you discover the data has changed and you need to redraw the bars. At that point you need to call setNeedsDisplay, which will trigger your drawRect to re-draw the chart.